# PySpark IPython - reduce RDD into a new RDD with different key

Tags: python, apache-spark, ipython, pyspark

First, I'm a newbie to Spark and Python. I'm trying to transform an RDD (resilient distributed dataset) into another one.

The input RDD is:

```
 (u'Task1', (u'James', 10)),
 (u'Task1', (u'James', 15)),
 (u'Task1', (u'James', 18)),
 (u'Task1', (u'James', 11)),
 (u'Task1', (u'Oliver', 10)),
 (u'Task1', (u'Oliver', 15)),
 (u'Task2', (u'Oliver', 18)),
 (u'Task2', (u'Oliver', 11)),
```

Now I'm trying to build a function that outputs the sum of hours for each person, no matter of the task:

```
def extract_time_tracking(time_bookings): 
    ???
    return (person, total_hours)
time_trackings_sum = input_RDD.???(extract_time_tracking)
```

The output should be:

```
 (u'James', 54), # has been working on Task1 only
 (u'Oliver', 54), # has been working on Task1 and Task2
```

I'm using PySpark IPython. I was thinking of combineByKey or reduceByKey, but they are always using the same key. But in my case the resulting key differs from the input key?!?!?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `map` function to transform the object so that the first element of the tuple is the key you want. Because you don't care about the task, you can actually drop it entirely.

```
input_RDD.map(lambda x: x[1]).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)
```

If, later, you want to simply shift the key, you would do a more complicated map:

```
input_RDD.map(lambda x: (x[1][0],(x[0],x[1][1]))
```

Comment: Could you explain the first lambda in the map function a bit more? why x[1]? the tuple would be task,<name, hours>

Comment: @Matthias Supposing x=(u'Task1', (u'James', 10)), x[0] will be u'Task1' and x[1] will be (u'James', 10), using the [normal tuple functionality](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). Since we're looking to calculate the hours by name, those are the two pieces of info we need. (More comments coming on other parts of this problem.)

Comment: The way to think about `map` is it transforms RDDs using an arbitrary function that you write. If you start off with an RDD whose objects have type X, and you want to have type Y, you write a map that will turn one X into one Y and then you apply it row by row in parallel. This problem needs only a simple transformation--throw away the task. Suppose instead we wanted to sum by tasks, and we have these names in the way. Then we do the following:

    `input_RDD.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1][1]).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)`

Comment: `reduceByKey` is a bit easier to think about in the Scala API, because it's a function only defined on tuples with two elements, of which the 0th one is the key and the 1st one is the value. In the PySpark API, it looks like it's a function of RDDs, and I have no clue what happens if you try to apply it to a RDD where the keys and values aren't as expected (for example, if the tuples were (u'Task1', u'James', 10), what would `reduceByKey` do?).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I read a bit more in detail though I wasn't familiar with Lambda expressions for Python. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
def extract_time_tracking(time_bookings): 
val splits = rec.split(",")
val person = splits(1).replaceAll(" \\(u'", "").replaceAll("'", "")
val total_hours = splits(2).replaceAll("\\)", "").trim().toInt
return (person, total_hours)


input_RDD.map(extract_time_tracking).reduceByKey
```

I use scala, so please check syntax.